# Nutrient loss upon throwing away water used to boil a food product

Tags: nutrition

If I boil a food product, say, chickpeas or corn in water- can I potentially lose any nutrients besides carbohydrates by throwing away the water as opposed to not throwing away the water? In what cases should I be careful (and in what cases can I throw away water without thinking)? I'm looking for the guiding principle (and not an exhaustive list).

Comment: Welcome to Health Stack Exchange! Here is a link that might help you: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/does-boiling-vegetables-wash-away-important-vitamins  , it's to another SE question. Thank you.